# parsing a quadratic equation in java

Tags: java, parsing, math, quadratic

I have to write a read method for a quadratic class where a quadratic is entered in the form ax^2 + bx + c = 0 I found this way and here's the code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class ParseEquation {
    public static String coeff(String str, String regex) {
        Pattern patt = Pattern.compile(regex);
        Matcher match = patt.matcher(str);
        // missing coefficient default
        String coeff = "+0"; 
        if(match.find()) 
                coeff = match.group(1);
        // always have sign, handle implicit 1
        return (coeff.length() == 1) ? coeff + "1" 
                : coeff;
    }

    public static String[] quadParse(String arg) {
        String str = ("+" + arg).replaceAll("\\s", "");

        String a = coeff(str, "([+-][0-9]*)x\\^2" );
        String b = coeff(str, "([+-][0-9]*)x(?!\\^)");
        String c = coeff(str, "([+-][0-9]+)(?!x)" );
        double a1 = Double.parseDouble(a);
        double b1 = Double.parseDouble(b);
        double c1 = Double.parseDouble(c);

        double dis = (Math.pow(b1, 2.0)) - (4 * a1 * c1);
        double d = Math.sqrt(dis);
        double X = 0,Y = 0; //root 1 & root 2, respectively

        if (dis > 0.0 || dis < 0.0 ) {
             X = (-b1 + d)/(2.0 * a1 );
             Y = (-b1 - d)/(2.0 *a1); 
             String root1 = Double.toString(X);
             String root2 = Double.toString(Y);
             return new String[]{root1,root2};
         } else if (dis == 0.0){
            X = (-b1 + 0.0)/(2.0 * a1);//repeated root
            String root2 = Double.toString(X);
            return new String[]{root2}; 
         }

         return new String[-1];
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (System.in));
        String s;
        while ((s=r.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] pieces = quadParse(s);
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(pieces));
        }
    }
}
```

this already solve normal 2nd degree equation ax^2 + bx + c = 0 ( any equation that user enter like "2x^2 + 2x -25 =0" for example) and solve it with changing the places of the roots either but I can't know how to solve equation that have similar roots like " 2x^2 + 2x -3x -25 +15 =0 " in this it should first sum the two coefficients of x and sum (-25+15 ) then calculate the result. So I need to know the way to know how to wrote code to do that.

Feel free to write any code as an example.

Comment: Have coeff use match.GroupCount to know how many coefficients there are and total them for you as doubles. That way coeff can simply return a double instead of a String. You would just have to loop and get each coefficient rather than only match.group(1).

Comment: Another possible, though less accurate and straightforward, approach is to use Lagrange polynomial interpolation, which is useful for quadratic equations in non-standard form.

Comment: When you say "roots", you mean "terms".  Terms are things that get added.  Roots are where the quadratic is zero.

Comment: @Teepeemm you're right this is just lack of focus from me

Comment: @stvcisco i have tried match.GroupCount but i could't make it right could u help me for that ?

Comment: If all my coefficients are composed of more than two this doesn't work, and I think the problem is the pattern of the "c" coefficient. Has anyone found a way to extract the "c" coefficient without perfectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to continuously add the values for `x^2` and `x`. I have modified the code and it seems to be working fine:

```
public class ParseEquation {
    public static double coeff(String str, String regex) {
        Pattern patt = Pattern.compile(regex);
        Matcher match = patt.matcher(str);
        // missing coefficient default
        String coeff = "+0";
        double value = 0;
        while(match.find()){
            coeff = match.group(1);
            value = value + Double.parseDouble(coeff);
        }
        // always have sign, handle implicit 1
        return (coeff.length() == 1) ? (value + 1) : value;
    }
    public static String[] quadParse(String arg) {
        String str = ("+" + arg).replaceAll("\\s", "");

        double a1 = coeff(str, "([+-][0-9]*)x\\^2");
        double b1 = coeff(str, "([+-][0-9]*)x(?!\\^)");
        double c1= coeff(str, "([+-][0-9]+)(?!x)");
        System.out.println("Values are a: " + a1 + " b: " + b1 + " c: " + c1);
        double dis = (Math.pow(b1, 2.0)) - (4 * a1 * c1);
        double d = Math.sqrt(dis);
        double X = 0, Y = 0; //root 1 & root 2, respectively

        if (dis > 0.0 || dis < 0.0) {
            X = (-b1 + d) / (2.0 * a1);
            Y = (-b1 - d) / (2.0 * a1);
            String root1 = Double.toString(X);
            String root2 = Double.toString(Y);
            return new String[]{root1, root2};
        } else if (dis == 0.0) {
            X = (-b1 + 0.0) / (2.0 * a1);//repeated root
            String root2 = Double.toString(X);
            return new String[]{root2};
        }
        return new String[-1];
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String s;
        while ((s=r.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] pieces = quadParse(s);
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(pieces));
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the output when I run the program:

`2x^2 + 2x -3x -25 +15 =0
Values are a: 2.0 b: -1.0 c: -10.0
[2.5, -2.0]`

So it is able to sum the coefficients correctly. I have not changed the logic written by you which IMO should be working fine.

Comment: thanks for your help but this code doesn't work and i couldn't make it work unfortunately, any help ?

Comment: @rk93 I have tried it with sample input and it works fine. Check my edit. It seems the code is working fine and you have some other problem. By the way what exactly is the problem you are facing?

Comment: This is exactly what I would suggest (have `coeff` return a `double` and sum them using `match.find()` in a `while` loop).  @rk93 you say you couldn't make it work - how is it failing after making these changes?

Comment: @akhil_mittal thanks for your help it was a stupid mistake from me working now

Answer (score 0):

final answer after edit to make it handle implicit 1

ex:
  x^2-3x-2x-25

Values are a: 1.0 b: -5.0 c: -25.0

[8.090169943749475, -3.0901699437494745]

```
public class ParseEquation {
public static String coeff(String str, String regex) {
    Pattern patt = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher match = patt.matcher(str);
    // missing coefficient default
    String coeff = "+0";
    double value = 0;

   if(match.find()) 
        coeff = match.group(1);
    // always have sign, handle implicit 1
    value= Double.parseDouble((coeff.length() == 1) ? coeff + "1" 
        : coeff);

    while(match.find()){

        coeff = match.group(1);
        value = value + Double.parseDouble(coeff);
    }
    String value2 =String.valueOf(value);
    return (value2.length() == 1) ? (value2 + "1") : value2;
}
public static String[] quadParse(String arg) {
    String str = ("+" + arg).replaceAll("\\s", "");

    double a1 = Double.parseDouble(coeff(str, "([+-][0-9]*)([a-z]\\^2)"));
    double b1 = Double.parseDouble(coeff(str, "([+-][0-9]*)([a-z](?!\\^))"));
    double c1= Double.parseDouble(coeff(str, "([+-][0-9]+)(?![a-z])"));
    System.out.println("Values are a: " + a1 + " b: " + b1 + " c: " + c1);
    double dis = (Math.pow(b1, 2.0)) - (4 * a1 * c1);
    double d = Math.sqrt(dis);
    double X = 0, Y = 0; //root 1 & root 2, respectively

    if (dis > 0.0 || dis < 0.0) {
        X = (-b1 + d) / (2.0 * a1);
        Y = (-b1 - d) / (2.0 * a1);
        String root1 = Double.toString(X);
        String root2 = Double.toString(Y);
        return new String[]{root1, root2};
    } else if (dis == 0.0) {
        X = (-b1 + 0.0) / (2.0 * a1);//repeated root
        String root2 = Double.toString(X);
        return new String[]{root2};
    }
    return new String[-1];
}
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String s;
    while ((s=r.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] pieces = quadParse(s);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(pieces));
    }
}
}
```