# Quadractic equation string processing in Java

Tags: java, regex, string, input

1. I have a question, how can we rewrite this code below so that when the user enter a string like this `5.6x^2+6x-3= -8x^2 + 2x - 5` the program can adapt as well. I know that we can solve this problem by regular expression, but the `=` sign seem to hinder a lot of my thinking.
2. what if I want to extract the co-eficients and put them in an array like this pseudo code how should I fix this code below ?

   ```
   arrayOfx^2[]={5.6, -8}
   arrayOfx^1[]={6, 2}
   arrayOfX^0[]={-3, -5}
   ```

The main reason for these 2 questions is that I am thinking of making an application that can provide step by step solution to quadratic equation like this. The answer could be like *"Combining the co-efficient of 5.6x^2 and -8x^2 together and obtain 13.6x^2"*, this would be much more pedagogical than just given the user the answer.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class ParseEquation_test {

    /**
     * @param str
     * @param regex
     * @return
     */
    public static String coeff(String str, String regex) {
        Pattern patt = Pattern.compile(regex);
        Matcher match = patt.matcher(str);
        // missing coefficient default
        String coeff = "+0";
        double value = 0;

        if (match.find()) {
            coeff = match.group(1);
        }
        // always have sign, handle implicit 1
        value = Double.parseDouble((coeff.length() == 1) ? coeff + "1"
                : coeff);

        while (match.find()) {

            coeff = match.group(1);
            value = value + Double.parseDouble(coeff);
        }
        String value2 = String.valueOf(value);
        return (value2.length() == 1) ? (value2 + "1") : value2;
    }

    public static String[] quadParse(String arg) {
        String str = ("+" + arg).replaceAll("\\s", "");

        double a1 = Double.parseDouble(coeff(str, "([+-][0-9]*)([a-z]\\^2)"));
        double b1 = Double.parseDouble(coeff(str, "([+-][0-9]*)([a-z](?!\\^))"));
        double c1 = Double.parseDouble(coeff(str, "([+-][0-9]+)(?![a-z])"));
        System.out.println("Values are a: " + a1 + " b: " + b1 + " c: " + c1);
        if (a1 == 0) {
            if (b1 == 0) {
                if (c1 == 0) {
                    String no_sol = "There are no solution";
                    return new String[]{no_sol};
                } else {
                    String infinite_sol = "There are infinitely many solutions";
                    return new String[]{infinite_sol};
                }
            } else {
                double sol_order1 = -c1 / b1;
                String final_sol_order1 = Double.toString(sol_order1);
                return new String[]{final_sol_order1};
            }
        } else {

            double dis = (Math.pow(b1, 2.0)) - (4 * a1 * c1);
            double d = Math.sqrt(dis);
            double X = 0, Y = 0; //root 1 & root 2, respectively

            if (dis > 0.0) {
                X = (-b1 + d) / (2.0 * a1);
                Y = (-b1 - d) / (2.0 * a1);
                String root1 = Double.toString(X);
                String root2 = Double.toString(Y);
                return new String[]{root1, root2};
            } else if (dis == 0.0) {
                X = (-b1 + 0.0) / (2.0 * a1);//repeated root
                String root2 = Double.toString(X);
                return new String[]{root2};
            } else if (dis < 0) {
                String no_sol = "There are no solution";
                return new String[]{no_sol};
            }
        }
        return new String[-1];
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO code application logic here
        System.out.println("Insert equation: ");
        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String s;
        while ((s = r.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] pieces = quadParse(s);
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(pieces));

        }
    }
}
```

The post related to this problem can be find here:

> [parsing a quadratic equation in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30009488/parsing-a-quadratic-equation-in-java)

I also modify the original code a bit so that it could also first order single variable equation as well as quadratic equation.

Comment: the `=` is a character like any other. I suggest you split on this character first and parse the left and right hand side.  Then take `[5.6, 6, -3]` and `[-8,  2, - 5]` and subtract one from the other to get `[13.6, 4, 2]` and solve as a quadratic equation.

Comment: Providing a step-by-step solution will probably be quite difficult though. Maybe this is a bit too difficult for a starting program?

Comment: Oh I just try to print some step for quadratic equation in a duck-tape manner, not really generalizing everything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by Peter Lawrey, split by the `=` and then process both sides of the equation separately. This can be done in following manner.

---

In order to extract the coefficients and the exponents you can use the regular expression below. You'll need to adjust it for Java, though (i.e. escaping `\`, etc.)

[`(?<coefficient>\[-+\]?(?:\d+\.)?\d+)(?:\[x\]\[\^\](?<exponent>\d))?`](https://regex101.com/r/CGbAsk/2)

It matches against an integer or decimal number, which it extracts as first group, called coefficient, followed by a variable with an exponent.

The exponent is captured by the second group, called exponent, and is optional. Since it is put in a non-capturing group `(?: ...)`, which is made optional  with a `?` suffix (i.e. only 0 or 1 occurrences are allowed).

Testing against `5.6x^2 +6x -3` yields three matches.

```
Match 1
Full match  0-6 `5.6x^2`
Group `coefficient` 0-3 `5.6`
Group `exponent`    5-6 `2`

Match 2
Full match  6-8 `+6`
Group `coefficient` 6-8 `+6`

Match 3
Full match  9-11    `-3`
Group `coefficient` 9-11    `-3`
```

As you can see, there still is a problem with matching the implicit `^1` in `+6x`. You could solve the problem by preprocessing the string and replacing every standalone `x` with `x^1`.

Also, spaces between signs and numbers (e.g. `- 6x^1` instead of `-6x^1`) lead to the sign being skipped, so they should be removed during preprocessing.

---

After you processed both sides of the equation, you can represent the coefficients and exponents as arrays and easily use them in numerous algorithms that solve equations.